# Testing a function in golang

Tags: testing, go

So I've decided to write test for my function in `golang`. The function itself looks like this:

```
func Insert(slice []int, element int, index int) []int {
    n := len(slice)
    slice = slice[:(n + 1)]
    for i := index; i < n; i++ {
        slice[i+1] = slice[i]
    }
    slice[index] = element
    return slice
}
```

So it takes a slice, extends its length by 1 and inserts an element at given index. Now before I call it I have to do 2 things:

```
size := somevalue
array := make([]int, size, size+1)
```

and then f.e `array = Insert(array, 1, len(array)/2`. Now I wrote `insert_test.go`:

```
package sdizo

import "testing"

func benchmarkInsert(size int, b *testing.B) {  
    b.ResetTimer()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        array := make([]int, size, size+1)
        array = Insert(array, 1, len(array)/2)
    }
}
func BenchmarkInsert10k(b *testing.B) { benchmarkInsert(10000, b) }
func BenchmarkInsert20k(b *testing.B) { benchmarkInsert(20000, b) }
func BenchmarkInsert30k(b *testing.B) { benchmarkInsert(30000, b) }
func BenchmarkInsert40k(b *testing.B) { benchmarkInsert(40000, b) }
func BenchmarkInsert50k(b *testing.B) { benchmarkInsert(50000, b) }
```

The thing is, there are 2 operations in testing loop. I cannot move the `make()` above the loop, cuz it has to make a new array everytime it tries to insert something to it (don't want to mess with capacity). It works, it gives me output, but I am curious if this `make()` doesn't mess up with time measurement, and I would like to ask you if I can somehow measure the time only for `Insert()`

P.S Is there a convenient way to write down the results of benchmark test to a file?

Comment: It is slightly flaky to implement a function in such a way: now you rely on the caller to provide a large enough slice, and panic otherwise.

Comment: I know, but how can I make it different, to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example (from Go 1.7 forward), using your `Insert` algorithm,

```
package sdizo

import (
    "strconv"
    "testing"
)

func Insert(slice []int, element int, index int) []int {
    n := len(slice)
    slice = slice[:(n + 1)]
    for i := index; i < n; i++ {
        slice[i+1] = slice[i]
    }
    slice[index] = element
    return slice
}

func BenchmarkInsert(b *testing.B) {
    for size := 10000; size <= 50000; size += 10000 {

        b.Run(strconv.Itoa(size/1000)+"k",

            func(b *testing.B) {
                a := make([]int, size, size+1)
                b.ReportAllocs()
                b.ResetTimer()
                for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                    a = a[:size]
                    a = Insert(a, 1, len(a)/2)
                }
                b.StopTimer()
            },
        )
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test -bench=.
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: sdizo
BenchmarkInsert/10k-4         50000      32502 ns/op       0 B/op      0 allocs/op
BenchmarkInsert/20k-4         20000      64364 ns/op       0 B/op      0 allocs/op
BenchmarkInsert/30k-4         20000      97310 ns/op       0 B/op      0 allocs/op
BenchmarkInsert/40k-4         10000     129196 ns/op       0 B/op      0 allocs/op
BenchmarkInsert/50k-4         10000     161427 ns/op       0 B/op      0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      so/sdizo    9.778s
$
```

Now that we can benchmark your `Insert` algorithm, we can use that knowledge to improve the algorithm. For example,

```
package sdizo

import (
    "strconv"
    "testing"
)

func Insert(slice []int, element int, index int) []int {
    slice = slice[:len(slice)+1]
    copy(slice[index+1:], slice[index:])
    slice[index] = element
    return slice
}

func BenchmarkInsert(b *testing.B) {
    for size := 10000; size <= 50000; size += 10000 {

        b.Run(strconv.Itoa(size/1000)+"k",

            func(b *testing.B) {
                a := make([]int, size, size+1)
                b.ReportAllocs()
                b.ResetTimer()
                for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                    a = a[:size]
                    a = Insert(a, 1, len(a)/2)
                }
                b.StopTimer()
            },
        )
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test -bench=.
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: sdizo
BenchmarkInsert/10k-4        200000       7664 ns/op       0 B/op      0 allocs/op
BenchmarkInsert/20k-4        100000      15208 ns/op       0 B/op      0 allocs/op
BenchmarkInsert/30k-4        100000      22959 ns/op       0 B/op      0 allocs/op
BenchmarkInsert/40k-4         50000      35181 ns/op       0 B/op      0 allocs/op
BenchmarkInsert/50k-4         50000      39658 ns/op       0 B/op      0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      so/sdizo    10.331s
$
```

Comment: One of my edits had a faster algorithm :P. Haha, sorry, just teasing. OP wasn't going for optimization anyway, so I removed the clutter from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The real answer you seek. (Finally)

When you benchmark, actually benchmark what you want to benchmark. Your use case isn't going to be a make, then insert every time, so just make once, then test insert in the loop. The point is to test ONLY the chokepoint.

What you want to do here is just test `Insert`. You can do this by simply resizing the array each time, the cost of which is basically nothing (at least in comparison to `make` or `Insert`).

```
func benchmarkInsert(size int, b *testing.B) { 
    array := make([]int, size, size+1) 
    b.ResetTimer()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        array = Insert(array, 1, len(array)/2)
        array = array[0:size]
    }
}
```

To explain why it is minimal, you have to realize that deep down, a slice is essentially a struct that looks something like this:

```
type Slice struct {
    contents []interface{}
    length   int
    capacity int
}
```

Performing the operation to resize it using `array = array[0:size]` is analogous to setting the struct's `length=size`. See https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

As far as writing the results to file, that depends on your operating system. On any Unix system, simply running the benchmark command with `> file.txt` at the end will pipe the results to `file.txt`. Not sure about Windows.

EDIT: Adding more tests shows this scales linearly.

```
BenchmarkInsert10k-8          200000          7889 ns/op
BenchmarkInsert20k-8          100000         16131 ns/op
BenchmarkInsert30k-8          100000         24184 ns/op
BenchmarkInsert40k-8           50000         31767 ns/op
BenchmarkInsert50k-8           50000         39721 ns/op
BenchmarkInsert100k-8          20000         79711 ns/op
BenchmarkInsert200k-8          10000        159411 ns/op
BenchmarkInsert300k-8           5000        237188 ns/op
BenchmarkInsert400k-8           5000        316270 ns/op
BenchmarkInsert500k-8           3000        399146 ns/op
BenchmarkInsert1000k-8          2000        793845 ns/op
```

Using this code: https://play.golang.org/p/6fWHwpzUJE

Comment: Faster, but isn't it incorrect? I think your `append` should go before the assignment of `element` to `pre[index]`. https://play.golang.org/p/ng7dX2rLKm

Comment: You are right, it is still referencing the same elements of the slice. I fixed it now. A new one has to be allocated, which slows things down. Still, this trick is about twice as fast... unfortunate that it isn't as cool as I originally thought. https://play.golang.org/p/GywtiP3Lun

Comment: @PaulHankin Ok, here, now it's super fast AND correct. https://play.golang.org/p/vdYQGXSZas

Comment: And what if I cannot use append (have to make about every algorithm by myself). And btw I checked your version, its faster, but the graph looks like this (should be aproximately a straight line) https://gyazo.com/ff670cd918aa89bbec8add2169ccf431

Comment: I mean the data you got is fine enough I guess (times get bigger x2, x1.5, x1.33, x1.25), but in my case its not. Did you change the tests somehow?

@Edit, okay I tested it on Windows and it works really nice, I guess I will have to say goodbye to Linux on VM :(

Comment: Oh, well if that's a requirement, then Go tricks are probably out... my bad. That wasn't mentioned in the question. As far as why the bench results seem off, it's because I forgot that I added the `n % 1000` stuff in. The memory allocation in the `make` is taking longer than your `Insert` code. So as far as the original benchmarking question goes, yes you MUST limit the number of calls to `make` because its cost far outweighs your function.

Comment: So by limiting the number of calls you mean what? :D

Comment: I'll add the benchmark function to show what I mean.

Comment: Okay, now I see. But then for what array sizes do you measure?

Comment: Turns out that tuning the value of `inserts` to 100 gives about the same results, which means that this 100 overhead in size is small enough to ignore when having your test sizes in the 10k+ range.

Comment: But why would you add it?

Comment: The way your insert function works requires there to be enough capacity in the slice or it will panic. It just creates the slice with 10k items, but it can grow to 10101 without having to reallocate a new one (which is what `append` will do for you automatically).

Comment: Okay, but I don't actually want `Insert()` to be universal. I did `make([]int, size, size+1` on purpose, that `+1` ensures that there will be no capacity problem. The program then gets 10k array (10k+1 capacity), adds 1 element, gets 20k array (20k+1 capacity), adds 1 element and so on

Comment: Finally came up with the best solution. `make` is called only once, and it does it on the exact size slice as you want it. I also cleaned up all the garbage in the answer so it's more clear.

Comment: Okay, so `array = array[0:size]` is measured as well, but its not as much time-consuming, so it doesn't really matter, right?

Comment: `BenchmarkInsert10k-4       50000             24307 ns/op
BenchmarkInsert20k-4       30000             45298 ns/op
BenchmarkInsert30k-4       10000            170921 ns/op
BenchmarkInsert40k-4        5000            232264 ns/op
BenchmarkInsert50k-4        5000            297310 ns/op` -> the first two are perfectly fine, but the other ones, ugh

Comment: Added explanation of why resizing is cheap. Along with documentation.

Comment: Okay, I get this, thank you :D But as I wrote before, there is a strange jump between 200k and 300k. I tested it several times, always the same. Between 100k and 200k there should be 2x time - okay, Between 200 and 300 1.5x -  there is NOT. But then again 300 and 400 -> 1.333333, and 400 and 500 -> 1.25. Why does it have this strange behaviour between 200k and 300k?

Comment: And I tested it for 10x smaller numbers (remove 0 for every one :D). And it works. The times are aproximately in a straight line. Is there maybe some type change, or something which appears on some number between 200k and 300k?

Comment: It scales linearly on my machine, not sure what's up on yours. I edited with benchmarks and the entire go source I ran it on.

Comment: Oh, it's because you are making the wrong assumption. Between those values you are not doubling, you will only get 2x time when you double, not go from 400 -> 500 etc.

Comment: Okay, I know. But from 100k to 200k I get the double. So from 200k to 300k I should get 1.5x, but I get like 4x, check the code I copied few comments ago